# Render twig template into html file using command in terminal

Tags: javascript, php, npm, twig, webpack

I am fan of webpack there is also [webpack-twig-loader](https://github.com/emilnordh/webpack-twig-loader), but it is unclear how it is working.

I want to run command in terminal like:

```
twigrender index.twig data.json
```

- which will output index.html from index.twig template using data from data.json as template variables.

Is that possible using for example webpack's webpack-twig-loader or [twig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twig) npm package?

Or can it be run using PHP in command line?

Next step would be using webpack dev server for autoloading to for twig templates, javascript and css.

Comment: Please spell-check your question title.